# BIND unstable with DLZ+MySQL on Ubuntu 9.10, any ideas?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, bind, ubuntu-9.10

My BIND server keeps dropping out and I can't work out why. Here is some info from the syslog that I think pertains to the failure(s):

```
Apr 22 21:12:17 dnsdebug named[6613]: mysql driver unable to return result set for lookup query
Apr 22 21:12:17 dnsdebug kernel: [285552.573949] type=1503 audit(1271963537.759:53): operation="open" pid=6618 parent=1 profile="/usr/sbin/named" requested_mask="::rw" denied_mask="::rw" fsuid=107 ouid=0 name="/dev/tty"
Apr 22 21:12:17 dnsdebug named[6613]: mysql driver unable to return result set for lookup query
Apr 22 21:13:17 dnsdebug named[6613]: last message repeated 7 times
```

Any ideas? Mysql had a segfault sometimes, but that seems to be no longer an issue. It's the 64bit version of ubuntu too.

Sometimes it will return records just fine, other times it appears to just randomly go down.

Answer (score 0):

If you enable debugging in Bind, it should print the SQL queries it's using.  When a query fails, try running it by hand and see if you have the same problem.  If it works for you, try running the query with the same use Bind is using and see if it works.

You can also use the logging tools in Mysql to try and pin down the problem.

Comment: Great, thanks. Any idea how enable debugging in BIND? How do I do the same for MySQL? Sorry for the basic question!